# Set fixed space between 2 views in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to learn to use layout constraints in interface builder but I am running across an issue...

I've got two views, one UILabel and one UIImageView, and I'd like a layout as follows:

1. the label should be centered in the superview
2. the imageview should be a set distance to the left of the label

Seems pretty simple, but I can't figure out how to impose a constraint for the second condition (the first is done automatically). Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on both views while holding the command key so they're both highlighted. Then click on the pin button in the bottom right hand corner of IB (the middle button). Select horizontal spacing and the constraint should now be added. You should be able to adjust it as needed from there.

[image: /Users/bvogelzang/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-03-22 at 12.55.19 PM.png]

Comment: How can we do same for ios5?

Comment: It does not work in xCode 5, horizontal spacing option does not appear in Pin menu.

Comment: why doesnt this work when both the `subview`s are inside a `stackview`?

Comment: You need to apply the spacing on the StackView in that case. Select the StackView, click on the Slider icon around the top right of the Interface builder. Type the spacing into the Spacing field